# JS: How to match one capture group multiple times in the same string?

Tags: javascript, regex

**The Situation**

I have a string that I want to match the same capture group multiple times. I need to be able to get at both matches.

**Example Code**

```
var curly = new RegExp("{([a-z0-9]+)}", "gi");
var stringTest = "This is a {test} of my {pattern}";

var matched = curly.exec(stringTest);
console.log(matched);
```

**The Problem**

Right now, it only shows the first match, not the second.

**JSFiddle Link**

http://jsfiddle.net/npp8jg39/

Comment: The asker seems to not will take the time to read the documentation.

Comment: ^ The whole point of this site is for people to ask how to do things they do not understand. Your answer provided no information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```js
    var curly = /{([a-z0-9]+)}/gi,
        stringTest = "This is a {test} of my {pattern}",
        matched;
    while(matched = curly.exec(stringTest))
        console.log(matched);
```

Comment: Note that the regexp must be specified in a separate variable. `while (/{[a-z0-9]+)}/gi.exec(stringTest))` doesnot shift the index and does not end well.

Answer (score 4):

Normally this is done by the `RegExp.exec` method but you know it's convoluted. Everytime I need to use it i have to look up to remember this stateful operation. It's like you need a state monad or something :)

Anyways. In recent JS engines there is this [`String.matchAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) which does the same thing in a much sane fashion by returning an iterator object.

```js
var curly = new RegExp("{([a-z0-9]+)}", "gi");
var stringTest = "This is a {test} of my {pattern}";

var matches = [...stringTest.matchAll(curly)];
console.log(matches);
```

If you need only the capture groups then just map the above result. Let's use `Array.from()` this time.

```js
var curly = new RegExp("{([a-z0-9]+)}", "gi");
var stringTest = "This is a {test} of my {pattern}";

var matches = Array.from(stringTest.matchAll(curly), m => m[1]);
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: The Array.from line in combination with the matchAll function were exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

The exec method must be used in a while loop if you want to treat several results. See the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).

Comment: I don't think "See the documentation" is really enough for an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Strings in JavaScript have a [`match` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) - you can use this to match all instances of a regular expression, returned as an array:

```
stringTest.match(curly);
```

This will return an array of matches:

```
> ["{test}", "{pattern}"]
```

To pull the inner values, you can use `substr`:

```
var arr = stringTest.match(curly);

arr[0] = arr[0].substr(1, arr[0].length - 2);
```

```js
> "test"
```

Or to convert the entire array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    arr[i] = arr[i].substr(1, arr[i].length - 2);
```

```js
> ["test", "pattern"]
```

Comment: I need to be able to get the string inside the capture group, though. Like "test" and "pattern".

Comment: +1, could you also include the code to do it with an `exec` loop, for iterative processing?