# NodeJS RegExp: how to access full list of results

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I'm having trouble accessing the full list of results when I `.exec()` a regular expression in Node. Here is my code:

```
var p = /(aaa)/g;
var t = "someaaa textaaa toaaa testaaa aaagainst";
p.exec(t);
> [ 'aaa', 'aaa', index: 4, input: 'someaaa textaaa toaaa testaaa aaagainst' ]
```

I only get two results, no matter what. Is my error on the RegExp itself?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Use `match`, `exec` will return only first match

Comment: Thanks! That's all I needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exec` will only return the first matched result. To get all the results

1. Use `match`

   ```
   var p = /(aaa)/g;
   var t = "someaaa textaaa toaaa testaaa aaagainst";
   var matches = t.match(p);
   ```

```js
var p = /(aaa)/g,
  t = "someaaa textaaa toaaa testaaa aaagainst";
var matches = t.match(p);

console.log(matches);
```

2. Use `while` with `exec`

   ```
   while(match = p.exec(t)) console.log(match);
   ```

```js
var p = /(aaa)/g,
  t = "someaaa textaaa toaaa testaaa aaagainst";

var matches = [];
while (match = p.exec(t)) {
  matches.push(match[0]);
}

console.log(matches);
```

Read: [match Vs exec in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753246/match-vs-exec-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

```
var p = /(aaa)/g;
var t = "someaaa textaaa toaaa testaaa aaagainst";
t.match(p);
```