# Array.join("") method not working JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm confused about why `array.join("")` is not working properly in this function.

If the letter is a-m it will show 0 and the otherwise is 1
`convertBinary("house")` ➞ "01110"

```js
function convertBinary(str) {
  var jack=str.split("")
  return jack.map(function(e) {
    var array=[]
    if(e.match(/[abcdefghijklm]/g)) {
      array.push(0)
    } else {
      array.push(1)
    }
    return array.join("");
  })
}
```

Where did I go wrong.

Comment: do you have some data and the given and wanted result?

Comment: Everything inside the function in the map is run for *each item* in the jack array. Also, map is designed to transform each item. You likely want to transform each item into 0 or 1, and so you should change your code to `return 0` or `return 1`. The map function will return the new array, so you should add `join("")` to the result of the map function. (NB - Your array inside the function inside map is not necessary - your code in this function just results in "0" or "1")

Comment: Why even have `array` in the first place? The parameter `e` is a single character, so the `map()` callback should return zero or one, not an array. Then you join at the end of the main function, not inside the map callback.

Comment: @NinaScholz I updated it in the post thanks

Comment: `map` always returns an array,

Comment: The code works fine, including `array.join()`. Read about [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: Here's all you need `return str.split("").map(c => +!/[a-m]/g.test(c)).join("");`

Comment: Get it thanks guys, just noobie here, appereciate everyone's help :D

Comment: BTW, you don't need `split` & `join`. You can use `replace` as `str.replace(/([a-m])|([^a-m])/g, (m, $1) => $1 ? 1 : 0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the `.join("")` to the **result** of the `map()` call, instead of inside the map() inner function, which also should return just `0` or `1` for each character.

Also it would be better to use `regex.test(str)` because we are only interested in *if* there is a match (true or false), see e.g. [what is the difference between .match and .test in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35308085/1220550).

Like this:

```js
function convertBinary(str) {
  var jack = str.split("")
  return jack.map(function(e) {
    if (/[abcdefghijklm]/.test(e)) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      return 1;
    }
  }).join("");
}

console.log(convertBinary("house"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize **array** and return **array.join()** outside the map function:

```js
function convertBinary(str) {
      var jack=str.split("");
      var array = jack.map(function(e){
        
        if(e.match(/[abcdefghijklm]/g)){
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
     })
     return array.join("");
    }
    console.log(convertBinary('house'));
```

Comment: If you're not using the return value you should use `forEach` instead of `map`. However declaring an empty array and filling it inside `forEach` is *exactly* why `map` exists...

Answer (score 0):

The array.join() must be outside the jack.map() function, like this:

```
var jack_bin = jack.map(function(e)
{
    var array=[]
    if(e.match(/[abcdefghijklm]/g))
    {
        return '0';
    }
    else
    {
        return '1';
    }
})
return jack_bin.join("");
```

Answer (score 0):

The key point here is that it should be fixed as `jack.map(...).join()`, because `jack.map()` returns an array.

```js
function convertBinary(str) {
    var jack=str.split("")
    return jack.map(function(e)
    {
        var array=[]
        if(e.match(/[abcdefghijklm]/g))
        {
            array.push(0)
        }
        else
        {
            array.push(1)
        }

        return array;
    }).join("")
    }
    
console.log(convertBinary("house")); // output is '01110'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution

```js
function convertBinary(str) {
      const jack = str.split('');
      const binArr =  jack.map(e => {
        if (e.match(/[abcdefghijklm]/g)) {
          return 0;
        } else {
          return 1;
        }
      });
      return binArr.join('');
    }
    
    
    console.log(convertBinary('house'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could short it a bit by using a chain of methods and use `test` instead of `match`, because you need a boolean value, not an array of matched items/null.

Then you need to take eiter `1` or `0` and join the result for getting a string.

```js
function convertBinary(string) {
    return string
        .split("")
        .map(function(e) {
            return /[abcdefghijklm]/.test(e) ? 1: 0;
        })
        .join('');
}

console.log(convertBinary("house")) // "01110"
```