# How to find everything between parentheses surrounding a given search term?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm new to regular expressions, and I couldn't figure out how to get this to work by just googling it. I think part of my problem might be that I'm having trouble phrasing the question in search terms.

**Here's my problem:**

I have a string that looks like this:

```
OSDfhosjdjakjdnvkjndkfvjelkrjejrijrvrvrjvnkrjvnkn(mint (light) green pants)shdbfhsbdhfbsjd(couch)hvbjshdbvjhsbdfbjs(forest (dark) (stained) green shirt) sjdfjsdhfjshkdfjskdjfksjdfhfskdjf(table)
```

I want to select the entire contents of the parentheses containing the word "green," and **only** those parentheses. That is to say, I want to return "mint (light) green pants" and "forest (dark) (stained) green shirt" but **not** "couch", "table", or any of the gibberish.

**What I've tried so far:**

- `/(.*?green.*?/)` seemed to return an almost arbitrary block of text surrounding "green" and beginning and ending with a /, which makes me think I screwed up escaping the parentheses somehow.
- `/(.*green.*/)` seemed to return the entire document.
- **Googling the problem:** It *seems* from the pages I'm finding here and on google that what I want is a lookbehind, a regex functionality that JavaScript doesn't support. Unfortunately, I'm working in JS, so I need a way to make this work.

**Edited:** I just realized that the text I want to be outputting contains more parentheses than I originally realized, and edited my example to reflect this.

Comment: An amazing resource for RexExp in JS is https://regexr.com/

Comment: Do you expect parenthesis to be balanced or is `(forest( green shirt)` still valid?

Comment: I expect parentheses to be balanced, yes.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of a lookahead you could make use of a capturing group. First match the opening parenthesis `\(` and then in a capturing group `(` match all until the closing parenthesis `\)`.

Your values will be in capturing group 1.

[`\(([^)]+\bgreen\b[^)]+)\)`](https://regex101.com/r/IYh4dQ/1)

**Explanation**

- `\(` Match opening parenthesis
- `([^)]+` Match not a `)` using a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)
- `\bgreen\b` Match the word green using word boundaries to make sure it is not part of a larger match
- `[^)]+` Match one or more times not a `)`
- `)` Close capturing group
- `\)` Match )

```js
const regex = /\(([^)]+\bgreen\b[^)]+)\)/g;
const str = `OSDfhosjdjakjdnvkjndkfvjelkrjejrijrvrvrjvnkrjvnkn(mint green pants)shdbfhsbdhfbsjd(couch)hvbjshdbvjhsbdfbjs(forest green shirt) sjdfjsdhfjshkdfjskdjfksjdfhfskdjf(table)`;
let m;
while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

**Edit**

To match the balanced parenthesis before `green`, you could match not a closing parenthesis one or more times or match balanced parenthesis using a non capturing group `(?:` and an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `(?:[^\)]+|\([^)]+\)`:

[`\(((?:[^\)]+|\([^)]+\))*\bgreen\b[^)]+)\)`](https://regex101.com/r/IYh4dQ/2)

```js
const regex = /\(((?:[^\)]+|\([^)]+\))*\bgreen\b[^)]+)\)/g;
const str = `OSDfhosjdjakjdnvkjndkfvjelkrjejrijrvrvrjvnkrjvnkn(mint (light) green pants)shdbfhsbdhfbsjd(couch)hvbjshdbvjhsbdfbjs(forest (dark) (stained) green shirt) sjdfjsdhfjshkdfjskdjfksjdfhfskdjf(table)`;
let m;
while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

Comment: This seems to return the parentheses too?

Comment: The values are in capturing group 1. That will not contain the parenthesis.

Comment: The parens are in the results when I test this? https://jsbin.com/wuzisoxesa/edit?js,console (Though as I mentioned to DanielBeck, I don't understand why.)

Comment: You can check this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/M9wnvQ/2) to see the capturing groups on the right side.

Comment: Ah, I get it. By just calling `str.match()` I am getting the full match, not what was captured in the capturing parens.

Comment: What should you call instead of str.match? Maybe that's part of my problem.

Comment: @Hexiva You could use `exec`. [This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753246/match-vs-exec-in-javascript?lq=1) has a nice explanation between the difference.

Comment: The fourth bird's answer does seem to account for the example I originally posted, but unfortunately the actual data has a lot of parentheses in parentheses (as the new example reflects). Sorry!

Comment: Sorry, but fails to capture `(green)`

Answer (score 1):

To match balanced parenthesis is not an easy problem and even harder to solve with JavaScript. Since the JS regex engine does not allow recursion. Let me cite [Steven Levithan](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/regex-recursion) on that matter:

> The problem, in this case, lies in how you distinguish between the
>   last closing bracket ... and any of the inner brackets. The only
>   difference between the last closing bracket and the inner brackets is
>   that they are logically linked (i.e., they form an open/close pair).
>   **This logic is impossible to implement by simple lookaround assertion.**

However, he concludes, if there is a known maximum amount of recursion that needs to be accounted for, it's possible.

Here's a solution that does not use any advanced regex features and works just fine with vanilla JavaScript.

```
\((?:\([^()]*?\)|([^()]*\bgreen\b[^()]*)?|[^()])*?\)
```

**Explanation**

- `\(` Match opening parenthesis
- `(?:...)` non-capputring group with **alternations**:

  - `\([^()]*?\)` Match inner pair of parenthesis, lazy match anything not a `()` using a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), non greedy
  - `([^()]*\bgreen\b[^()]*)?` Capture the optional word green with word boundaries in group 1, greedy
  - `[^()]` a "modified dot": anything not a `()` to keep parenthesis balanced
- `*?` Close the non-capturing group, match zero or more times lazy
- `\)` Match )

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/RlNf6T/3)

I use an extra capture group to meet the requirement with the given search term; if there is no $1 the full match is trash:

Sample Code:

```js
const regex = /\((?:\([^()]*?\)|([^()]*\bgreen\b[^()]*)?|[^()])*?\)/gm;
const str = `OSDfhosjdjakjdnvkjndkfvjelkrjejrijrvrvrjvnkrjvnkn(mint (light) green pants)shdbfhsbdhfbsjd(couch)hvbjshdbvjhsbdfbjs(forest (dark) (stained) green shirt) sjdfjsdhfjshkd(fjskdjfksjdfhfskdjf(green table) (green)`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
      if(match && groupIndex === 1)
        console.log(`Found ${m[0]}`);
    });
}
```

Caveats, this works only if:

- braces are actually balanced,
- and the level of brace nesting is no more than one.
  If more levels are needed, adjust the pattern as shown by Steven.